# Add individual custom headers in different controllers in web api using Swasbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

How can I add individual headers on different controllers.
E.g.:

Controller Name: Controller1,
Custom header: Header1

Controller Name: Controller2,
Custom header: Header2

The headers should be displayed for all the apis under the specific controller

Answer (score 8):

This can be solved by adding an OperationFilter to your swagger configuration. 
First you have to provide a class that implements `IOperationFilter`. The `Apply`method receives an `Operation` parameter which contains the controller name in the `tag`field. When the Swagger UI is rendered, the `Apply`method will be called for each method in the API. You could even provide individual parameters for each API method, as `Operation`  also contains the operationId.

```c#
public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        if (operation.tags[0]?.CompareTo("Example") == 0)
        {
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "X-ExampleParam",
                @in = "header",
                @default = "42",  // optional default value, can be omitted
                type = "string",
                description = "My special parameter for the example API",
                required = true
            });
        }
        else if (operation.tags[0]?.CompareTo("Whatever") == 0)
        {
        // add other header parameters here
        }
    }
}
```

In the debugger, with a controller named `ExampleController`, it looks like this:

[image: debug output]

The result in the Swagger UI is a special parameter that is only applied to the API of my Example controller:
[image: swagger ui showing special parameter]

Tell Swagger to use your OperationFilter by adding one line in the `Register` method of the `SwaggerConfig` class:

```c#
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        config
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                ... // omitted some lines here
                c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>(); // Add this line
                ... // omitted some lines here
                })

     }
```

The idea to this solution is based on ShaTin's answer: [How to send custom headers with requests in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180615/how-to-send-custom-headers-with-requests-in-swagger-ui)

Answer (score -2):

This is not an answer but stackoverflow wont' let me just make a comment on the solution from jps.  Just wanted to add this is what I needed for my using clauses in jps's answer to get this to work in regular .net:

```
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
```