# Swagger with spring boot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, filter, swagger, microservices, swagger-ui

I have a **microservice-A** which gets the token as a header from another **microservice-B**. Now I want to implement **swagger2 in microservice-A**. The problem is every request **flows through microservice-B**. So **swagger-ui throws error** in local as

> it is not able to get those header parameter which microservice-B is
>   trying to fetch.

Comment: what is your question, be specific!

Comment: @AkshayRohilla My question is...is there any way to pass header, for ex. JWT token to swagger request?

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41180615/3503187) is what you are asking.

Comment: @Ubercool I am unable to get the swagger-ui itself.
I have some filters applied, swagger-ui is trying to go through those filters and failing.

Comment: can you update the question with classes where you have configured swagger-ui

Answer (score 0):

> It is not able to get those header parameter which microservice-B is trying to fetch.

`Swagger` on its own can't call the authenticator service and add the obtained token to another request's header.

You can modify the `Docket` object to accept additional parameter in header as below:

```
docket.globalOperationParameters(
    Collections.singletonList(new ParameterBuilder()
      .name("Authorization")
      .description("Bearer [token]")
      .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
      .parameterType("string")
      .required(true)
      .build()
    )
);
```

This will allow Swagger UI to show additional field to accept token (see image below). You need to obtain the token by yourself and can put in this field.

[image]Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is...every request flows through one of the microservice, then gets redirected to another microservice, even the swagger hits the microservice first and fails as there is no token in the header. So the UI doesn't generate, it gives error.

Comment: Can't help more without looking at code or error stack