# What are the best practices in adding custom header fields for a .net web api call on Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, swagger, swagger-ui

I can see a lot of ways to do it online but most of them are messy, for me I was using these two ways

- Using scopes, I did one for mobile and another one for the website

  ```
  var webScope = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline()
     .Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
     .OfType<WebAuthorize>()
     .SelectMany(attr => attr.Roles.Split(','))
     .Distinct();

  var mobileScope = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline()
      .Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
      .OfType<MobileAuthorize>()
     .SelectMany(attr => attr.Roles.Split(','))
     .Distinct();
  ```

  And it worked because I had two different ways in authorizing the api calls, as you can see I had a Mobile Authorize and a Web Authorize so my api calls would look something like this:

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("something")]
  [WebAuthorize(Code = PermissionCode, Type =PermissionType)]
  public async Task<Dto> Getsomething()
  {
      return await unitOfWork.GetService<ISomething>().GetSomething();
  }
  ```

  Issues I face when using scopes is that all calls that have web authorize will share the same headers so for the special calls I used another way to add custom headers.
- Using apiDescription.RelativePath, and I will check it if the relative path is equal to the api call I want to add that custom header, example:

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("rename")]
  [InHouseAuthorize(Code = PermissionCode, Type =PermissionType)]
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RenameDevice()
  {
      HttpRequestMessage request = Request ?? new HttpRequestMessage();
      String deviceName = request.Headers.GetValues("deviceName").FirstOrDefault();
      String deviceGuid = request.Headers.GetValues("deviceGuid").FirstOrDefault();
      await unitOfWork.GetService<IDeviceService>().RenameDevice(deviceGuid, deviceName);
      await unitOfWork.Commit();
      return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  }
  ```

  And then I would add to the AddRequiredHeaderParameter.cs the following

  ```
      if (apiDescription.RelativePath.Contains("device/rename"))
      {
          operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
          {
              name = "deviceGuid",
              @in = "header",
              description = "Add the Device Guid",
              type = "string",
              required = false
          });
          operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
          {
              name = "DeviceName",
              @in = "header",
              description = "Add the Device Name",
              type = "string",
              required = false
          });
      }
  ```

  At first this was convenient and good enough fix but things are turning ugly as I'm adding a lot of calls that need custom headers and if the same URL have a Get and Post then it will even get uglier.

I am searching for the best way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use attribute [FromHeader] for web methods parameters (or properties in a Model class) which should be sent in custom headers. Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Products([FromHeader(Name = "User-Identity")]string userIdentity)
```

For me it looks like the easiest solution. At least it works fine for ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.5.0.

Comment: This solution was working fine for me but when I'm doing some testing I noticed that Swagger decided to consider my headers as queries and not as headers, any clue what may have caused it?