# Add a filter for a header in Swagger for ASP .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have followed this:

[Web Api How to add a Header parameter for all API in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493130/web-api-how-to-add-a-header-parameter-for-all-api-in-swagger)

and this:

[How to send custom headers with requests in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180615/how-to-send-custom-headers-with-requests-in-swagger-ui)

However, none of these IParameter, Parameter or NonBodyParameters work on ASP .NET CORE 3.1.

I would like to add a header on my swagger which takes a tenant-ID that is preferably taken from the logged user.

I have also went through this as well:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Operations;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace Intent2.Auth.Utils
{
    public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
            {
                Name = "X-User-Token",
                In = "header",
                Type = "string",
                Required = false
            });
        }
    }
}
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
}
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL I have added it , but it cannot find the namespaces as mentioned above. That is why I was looking for an alternative.

Comment: I just edited my answer for a detail. I think you should actually write `Required = true` considering the class name is `AddRequiredHeaderParameter`. If my question solved your issue please consider marking it as accepted answer (different than an upvote).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the latest version of Swashbuckle compatible with ASP.NET Core 3.1 many types have been replaced by equivalent types in the `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models` namespace. So you shouldn't use anymore types like `NonBodyParameter` or `IParameter`. Both of these have been replaced by a single class `OpenApiParameter`.

Your code should look like this

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Intent2.Auth.Utils
{
    public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {

            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter()
            {
                Name = "X-User-Token",
                Description = "Access Token",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "String" },
                Required = true,
                Example = new OpenApiString("Tenant ID example")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your startup, simply inject SwaggerGen as usual

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
}
```

You can even make the Tenant ID coming from the outside like a configuration file for example. To do that, modify your `AddRequiredHeaderParameter` as follow

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Intent2.Auth.Utils
{
    public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
    {
        private string _tenantIdExample;

        public AddRequiredHeaderParameter(string tenantIdExample)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantIdExample )) 
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tenantIdExample ));

            _tenantIdExample = tenantIdExample;
        }

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {

            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter()
            {
                Name = "X-User-Token",
                Description = "Access Token",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "String" },
                Required = true,
                Example = new OpenApiString(_tenantIdExample)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And call it that way from your startup

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>("Tenant ID example");
}
```

By the way I think if your class is called `AddRequiredHeaderParameter` you should actually set `Required = true` instead of `false`

Comment: Thank you. Where do I set the tenantId here? Is it on the "In" parameter?

Comment: Jerome that helped a lot. What I get now is this https://imgur.com/a/aTEWlqs

IS it possible to have the value predefined in that header cell?

Comment: @grozdeto I just edited my code to include the Tenant ID example

Comment: Jerome I really appreciate your help and thank you for the detailed answer. You really helped me solve this task. A big part of it was finding what were the names of the parameters. I hope it helps other members as well.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL From the UI the value is not being passed to the back-end. The `context.Request.Headers` doesnot have the header that X-User-Token header. What might be the issue?