# JWT authentication stops working after upgrading from .netcore2.2 to .netcore3.1

Tags: swashbuckle, jwt, .net-core-3.1

After upgrading,

In the Swagger UI I can create a bearer token but I get a 401 when I try to use it.

In the error log I see

> AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated

and

> "POST" requests are not supported

and

> Request successfully matched the route with name 'null' and template

```
2020-09-01 04:58:25.004 +10:00 [Information] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] [{ Id: 1 }] Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44348/api/job-management/get-user-counts application/json 18
2020-09-01 04:58:25.005 +10:00 [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler] [{ Id: 9, Name: "AuthenticationSchemeNotAuthenticated" }] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated.
2020-09-01 04:58:25.005 +10:00 [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware] [{ Id: 1, Name: "MethodNotSupported" }] "POST" requests are not supported
2020-09-01 04:58:25.005 +10:00 [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.RewriteMiddleware] [{ Id: 1, Name: "RequestContinueResults" }] Request is continuing in applying rules. Current url is "https://localhost:44348/api/job-management/get-user-counts"
2020-09-01 04:58:25.006 +10:00 [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware] [{ Id: 1, Name: "MethodNotSupported" }] "POST" requests are not supported
2020-09-01 04:58:25.006 +10:00 [Debug] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter] [{ Id: 1, Name: "RequestMatchedRoute" }] Request successfully matched the route with name 'null' and template '"api/job-management/get-user-counts"'
```

I thought of generating a new sample api using VS2019, however I can not find one for JWT

[image: Change Authentication Dialog]

In ConfigureServices I have added

```
services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

How should I go about troubleshooting my issue?

[Update]

I have looked through the Microsoft Upgrade guidelines but am not spotting that I have missed anything.

Comment: Did you follow the migration guides from microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I think the answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522015/add-a-filter-for-a-header-in-swagger-for-asp-net-core-3-1 I am just cross checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522015/add-a-filter-for-a-header-in-swagger-for-asp-net-core-3-1)

I had correctly converted to use OpenApiParameter but I had missed the step of

```
 Schema = new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "String" }
```

I am thinking my question is not a duplicate because the errors I got may assist someone else in finding the answer.