# "error": "Unsupported Media Type" on Upload File Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, swagger, http-status-code-415

I have a simple project that works on PDF files. I am trying to code a File Upload Controller.
I've tried lots of ways to do this but it keeps giving me this error :

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykuss6O97yqzGx0dG' not supported]
```

Here is my code:

```java
@PostMapping (value = "/setTemplateContent", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOperation(value= "Get contract and pdf. Save Pdf in Contract", notes = "Convert pdf to ByteArray")
@ResponseBody
public void setTemplateContent(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
        throws IOException {
}
```

I am using Swagger UI to send requests.

[image: Swagger Post Method Image]

I've even tried to implement the "Getting Started" example from Spring's official guide website. I cannot see where is my problem. Can you help me to see my problem?

Comment: Are you setting the Content-Type: application/pdf header when sending the request?

Comment: Well Swagger asks me nothing about the header. You can check my post configs from the Swagger Post Method Image

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Well, if you're using Swagger Inspector, setting a header is pretty straightforward. If using Swagger UI, you can specify a header in the text specification like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180615/how-to-send-custom-headers-with-requests-in-swagger-ui

Comment: Your request is multipart form data, so it has to use something like `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` instead of `APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE`

Comment: @Helen Thank you for the edit and advice. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Helen It is not possible to add  `@Consumes` to the code. But i managed to add like `@PostMapping (value = "/setTemplateContent", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)`  but again it is not working. Now i got the error of  `"Required request part 'file' is not present",`

Comment: Well still i couldn't manage to find an answer but i decided to solve this issue with the help of BASE64.