# How to check of an action allowes anonymous access or if only authorized?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, asp.net5

I have an ASP.NET 5 based project. I am using SwaggerUI to generate the documentation. I need to implement the `IOperationFilter` to add required parameters to any route that does not allow Anonymous access.

With the Swagger operation filter, I do have access to the `ControllerActionDescriptor`. However, I can't find a successful way to check of the action allows anonymous access or not.

Here is what I have done

```
public class AddTenantHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var filterDescriptor = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
            bool isAuthorized = filterDescriptor.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAsyncAuthorizationFilter);
            bool allowAnonymous = filterDescriptor.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter);

            if (!isAuthorized || allowAnonymous)
            {
                // we don't need to add header for anonymous allowed actions
                return;
            }

            //.. add the headers
        }
    }
```

The problem in the above code is that I get `false` value for both `isAuthorized` and `allowAnonymous` even when some actions are decorated with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and others have the `[Authorize]` attribute decorated at the controller level.

How can I correctly tell if an action allows anonymous access or authorized access only?

Comment: Have you added your filter to the service definition? I do not have my own implementation of `IOperationFilter` but it will show a lock or unlocked based upon the `[Authorize]` attribute. i.e. in `services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>` make sure you have `c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();`

Comment: Hi @Jay, Did my answer help you resolve your issue? If so, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need change your code like below to judge if the action or controller  is declared with `Authorize`/`AllowAnonymous` attribute:

```
public class AddTenantHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {       
        bool isAuthorized = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() ||
           context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();
        bool allowAnonymous = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any() ||
           context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();

        if (!isAuthorized || allowAnonymous)
        {
            // we don't need to add header for anonymous allowed actions
            return;
        }

        //.. add the headers
    }
}
```